# Get 'following' from the url - domain.com/following#2

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, fragment

looking to get the value after the domain but before anything else.

So an example of the URL would be:

```
www.domain.com/following#2
```

I only want to get the word following out of that url.

Currently have this which redirects a user and gets data after any fragments etc:

```
// First get the page URL and split it via # and ? signs
var parts = location.href.split('#');
var queryParameters = location.search.split('?');

// Now we get the value of the page value in the URL if there is one
var pageNumber = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < queryParameters.length; i++)
 {
 var keyvaluePair = queryParameters[i].split('=');
 if(keyvaluePair[0] == 'page')
 {
   pageNumber = keyvaluePair[1];
   break;
 }
}

// Next we check how many parts there are in the URL and if this a value, we add it to the current page
// and redirect to that new page number
if(parts.length > 1)
{
  var params = parts[0].split('?');
  var mark = '?';
  if(params.length > 1)
  {
    mark = '?';
  }
  var newPageNumber = parseInt(parts[1], 10) + parseInt(pageNumber, 10);
  location.href = mark + 'page=' + newPageNumber;
}
```

So out of the URL, i need to change this line:

```
location.href = mark + 'page=' + newPageNumber;
```

To

```
location.href = following + mark + 'page=' + newPageNumber;
```

But i will use a variable instead of following depending on what i take from the URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try location.pathname. Doing this should return the "path" or whatever is after the backslash

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to obtain that text:

```
var regex = /\/(.*)#/;
var url = 'www.domain.com/following#2';

var result = url.match(regex);
if (result.length > 0) {
    console.log(result[result.length - 1]);
}
```

Disclaimer - this particular example won't work with `http://` at the start of the URL, but I have used the URL from your question.

Comment: You could make it work with `http://` by making the `.*` non-greedy by using `.*?` instead.

Comment: I'm sure there would be a way - I haven't yet found one that works though :) - working version! http://jsfiddle.net/nkfq5/1/